# How to display paragraphs as a horizontal list?

Tags: html, css

I want my site to have an about section with one (col-1) section above others.
And underneath that section, 3 columns which describe 3 aspects of my life.

I tried inline-block and can't get it working, but I would really like this method to succeed because of its flexibility.

html

```
<body>
  <section class="about">
    <h1>WHO I AM</h1>
    <div class="col-1">
      <h3>About me</h3>
      <p>sometihing
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3">
      <h3>My work</h3>
      <p>Something
      </p>
    </div><br>
    <div class="col-3">
      <h3>Ambitions</h3>
      <p>Something
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3">
      <h3>Accomplishments</h3>
      <p>Something
      </p>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>
```

css

```
.about {
  h1 {
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 200%;
  }
  p {
    line-height: 200%;
  }
  color: white;
  .col-1 {
    text-align: center;
    margin-right: 20em;
    margin-left: 20em;
  }

  .col-3 {
    display: inline-block;
  }
}
```

This is what I get:
http://prntscr.com/mdwl74.
This is what I want to get:
http://prntscr.com/mdwkt6.

P.S. my body has id home

Answer (score 4, accepted):

flexbox is a good tool for this. You only need one wrapper Element (flexbox-container).

```css
.flexbox-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <section class="about">
    <h1>WHO I AM</h1>
    <div class="col-1">
      <h3>About me</h3>
      <p>sometihing
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="flexbox-container">
      <div class="col-3">
        <h3>My work</h3>
        <p>Something
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-3">
        <h3>Ambitions</h3>
        <p>Something
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-3">
        <h3>Accomplishments</h3>
        <p>Something
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

the `float`, `box-sizing`, and `width` property are both important here:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.col-1 {
  text-align: center;
}

.float-next {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
}

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <section class="about">
    <h1>WHO I AM</h1>
    <div class="col-1">
      <h3>About me</h3>
      <p>sometihing
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3 float-next">
      <h3>My work</h3>
      <p>Something
      </p>
    </div><br>
    <div class="col-3 float-next">
      <h3>Ambitions</h3>
      <p>Something
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3 float-next">
      <h3>Accomplishments</h3>
      <p>Something
      </p>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>
```