# Paragraf table, bottom side has chunky sides

Tags: html, css

With the code shown here I get this strange chunks in different resolutions of browser. I kinda solved solution, if chunks start depends on the resolution of the page and amount of things in the box so I filled them enough to align perfectly. But I want a solution for every resolution to work perfectly .

This is what happens: http://prntscr.com/mec8r3

I only tried `<br>` and it doesn't work, I have no idea what to do

```
<section class="about">
            <div class="col-1">
              <h3>About me</h3>
              <p>smh
              </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 float-next">
              <h3>My work</h3>
              <p>smh
              </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 float-next">
              <h3>Ambitions</h3>
              <p>smh
              </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 float-next">
              <h3>Accomplishments</h3>
              <p>smh
              </p>
            </div>
          </section>

.about{
        background-color:$color-gray;
        color:$color-main;
    }
    .col-1 {
        transition: 0.5s;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 2em 20em 2em 20em;
            p{
                font-size: 18px;
                line-height: 200%;
            }
      }
      .col-1:hover{
          transition: 0.5s;
          background-color: $color-black;
      }

      .float-next {
        float: left;
        width: 33.33%;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 10px 0 1em;
        background-color: $color-gray;
        font-size: 18px;
        line-height: 200%;
        transition: 0.5s;
      }
      .float-next:hover{
          transition: 0.5s;
          background-color:$color-black;
      }
      .col-3{
        padding: 5em ;
      }
      .row:after {
        content: "";
        display: table;
        clear: both;
      }
```

Perfect table of content with a str8 line at the bottom

Comment: How's this question different from [your last one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54428181/how-to-display-paragraphs-as-a-horizontal-list)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a big part of the problem is when you use floats, that element is taken out of the flow. The other elements around it basically ignore it.  Try using flexbox. At this point you should be using flexbox instead of floats anyway. [Here is a great guide for flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). Its not super clear what you want so heres a [Codepen](https://codepen.io/pen?editors=1100) with a guess of what you want. If you wanted something else please leave a mockup of what you want it to look like. Hope this helps.

```css
.about{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.col-1{
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  min-height: 80px;
  background: #283593;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.col-3{
  background: #00ACC1;
  width: 33.333333%;
  text-align: center;
  min-height: 80px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so uch , it acctuly worked , i never knew that there are things like flex-boxes !

Comment: No problem! Good luck to you.